# How can I create and setup an litcoin mining pool?

Tags: mining-pools, litecoin

I am researching if it is viable to create a mining pool on some closed networks outside of normal operating hours.

Is there a system which can be customise which shows accountability of running such a mining pool?  I want to make sure we can prove the electricity usage and offer a fair reward for all concerned obviously.

We have some participants who have supercomputers handy too, would that cause any complication due to skewing the performance too heavily?

How can we calculate the power needed to mine a single LTC coin (on average)?

Comment: "How can we calculate the power needed to mine a single LTC coin (on average)?" would be best asked as a separate question.

Comment: there is an answer how to install a mining pool 

[http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/how-to-setup-pushpool/5995#5995?newreg=6410e50683ed49f0bf829d0c865c4ca4][1]


  [1]: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4303/how-to-setup-pushpool/5995#5995?newreg=6410e50683ed49f0bf829d0c865c4ca4