# How do you setup your own Bitcoin / Litecoin / Primecoin / Altcoin pool? Whats a good tutorial?

Tags: mining-pools, datacoin

I was wondering how would one setup their own pool for one of the alt coins. Is there a good tutorial link on how to setup your own pool? I'm mainly looking to setup a datacoin pool but was wondering how to get that up.

Comment: I also want to know this. :^)

Comment: me too looking for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find my answer on how to start mining Bitcoins useful, as it touches on setting up your own pools:

[How can I start mining Bitcoin?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/1433/how-can-i-start-mining-bitcoin/22916#22916)

Also this post goes into a bit more detail on using Stratum + Push Pool.

[How to setup stratum with pushpool and VARDIFF? (litecoin)](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10044/how-to-setup-stratum-with-pushpool-and-vardiff-litecoin/23028#23028)

Some info on eloipool configuration:

[Managing Diff variable on eloipool software](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/25102/managing-diff-variable-on-eloipool-software/25150#25150)

If you wanted some more specific information let me know.