# Managing Diff variable on eloipool software

Tags: mining-pools, difficulty

I'm trying to set up a pool of Bitcoin Mining. I use a software program eloipool.
https://gitorious.org/bitcoin/eloipool
I can not find the configuration file options to force a change of Diff. So that I want to manually specify the value Diff. Tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set it in config.py,

Line 22:
This is the minimum difficulty for your main mining coin (e.g. Bitcoin)

ShareTarget = 0x00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff

if you are wanting to setup merged mining the difficulty for that is controlled by line 161 one config.py:

GotWorkTarget = 0x00000000ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff

Hope that helps.